# Icons with Text located beside it

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use custom icons (3 of them) be located in their own cell in a table with the cell directly beside them being the text that goes along with them.  I want the text to be close to the image.  The image is to enlarge slightly when hovered over as it will also be a hyperlink.  I can't seem to get code to ensure it is aligned center of the page and formatted correctly.  Also the scale isn't working when I set it to enlarge on hover.

I have already tried multiple codes but none seem to be working within sharepoint.

```css
.demo-problem,
.demo-solution {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

body {
  padding: 30px;
}

.outer-div {
  padding: 30px;
}

.inner-div {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.demo-solution--flexbox {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

img3 {
  width: 25%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}

img3:hover {
  transform: scale(3);
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo-solution demo-solution--flexbox">
  <div class="outer-div">
    <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="https://ontariopowergeneration.sharepoint.com/:i:/r/sites/powernet/support/res/PublishingImages/Pages/Real%20Estate/Icons/ICON_Real-Estate.png?csf=1&e=acVaiZ" alt="" class="img3"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-div"><span><blockquote>Corporate Real Estate & Workplace</blockquote></span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: In case you didn't know: Code-Snippets have an inbuild autoformat button: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwGHH.png

Answer (score 1):

The `img3` is a class so u need to specify
`.img3` whereas you have done just `img3`.
If you change it to .img3 scale works

```css
.demo-problem,
.demo-solution {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

body {
  padding: 30px;
}

.outer-div {
  padding: 30px;
}

.inner-div {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.demo-solution--flexbox {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.img3 {
  width: 25%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}

.img3:hover {
  transform: scale(3);
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo-solution demo-solution--flexbox">
  <div class="outer-div">
    <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="https://www.slipperelectrical.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/dummy-image.jpg" alt="" class="img3"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-div"><span><blockquote>Corporate Real Estate & Workplace</blockquote></span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: In case you didn't know: Code-Snippets have an inbuild autoformat button: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwGHH.png